# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql, collation

We started getting the below error all of a sudden on the login page of our Portal:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) 
>   AND (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) FOR operation '='

from this query:

```
SELECT  `corporate_department`.`dep_id`, `corporate_department`.`dep_name`, 
        `corporate_department`.`transaction_limit`, `corporate_department`.`dep_status`, 
        (SELECT SUM(corporate_transactions.amount) FROM   corporate_transactions 
         WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(corporate_transactions.transaction_date, '%Y-%m') = '2020-01' 
         AND corporate_transactions.department_id = corporate_department.dep_id 
         AND corporate_transactions.trip_id NOT IN 
              (SELECT trip_id FROM trip_flags WHERE flag_id != 2 
               GROUP BY trip_id 
               HAVING COUNT(trip_id) = 1 ) AND corporate_transactions.trip_id NOT IN 
                        (SELECT  trip_id FROM trip_flags WHERE flag_id = 2 
                         GROUP BY trip_id HAVING COUNT(trip_id) > 1 ) ) AS amount, 
        (SELECT COUNT(corporate_transactions.trip_id) FROM corporate_transactions 
         WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(corporate_transactions.transaction_date, '%Y-%m') = '2020-01' 
         AND corporate_transactions.department_id = corporate_department.dep_id 
         AND corporate_transactions.trip_id NOT IN 
              (SELECT trip_id FROM trip_flags WHERE flag_id != 2 
               GROUP BY trip_id 
               HAVING COUNT(trip_id) = 1 ) AND corporate_transactions.trip_id NOT IN 
                         (SELECT trip_id FROM trip_flags WHERE flag_id = 2 
                          GROUP BY trip_id HAVING COUNT(trip_id) > 1 )) AS rides 
FROM     `corporate_department` 
WHERE    `corporate_department`.`corporate_company` = 60 
AND      `corporate_department`.`dep_status` IN (A, D) 
GROUP BY `corporate_department`.`dep_id` 
ORDER BY `corporate_department`.`dep_name` ASC)
```

The 3 tables involved in the above query has the following character set and collation set:

```
                        character_set           collation

corporate_transactions.  utf8.                  utf8_unicode_ci(defined in table)
trip_flags               utf8                   utf8_general_ci(not defined, but is the default value for utf8) 
corporate_department.   latin1                  latin1_swedish_ci(4842)
```

There are no collation defined on the column level and there were no changes made on the table definition either, but there were some changes made about 1 week ago from the app side. Can someone help me understand what could be the issue here?

Comment: Perhaps some new data was added to one or more of the tables which is causing this problem.  The problem can occur when MySQL isn't able to automatically figure out how to compare data from two different tables having different collations.

Comment: Use explicit charset/collation  in `... AND corporate_transactions.trip_id NOT IN ( SELECT trip_id FROM trip_flags ...`. For example, `... AND corporate_transactions.trip_id NOT IN ( SELECT trip_id COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci FROM trip_flags ...`. Read [Collation Coercibility in Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-coercibility.html).

Comment: Of course it is possible that there is more problematic points - fix them all. And I'd recommend to specify default charset and collation on the database level...

Comment: Thank you for the help. We are now going ahead with the Akina's suggestion to explicity define the collation in the query itself, will update here the result